# How to avoid mirroring remote directory parents with rsync?

Tags: rsync

I am running this command:

`rsync -zavrR --delete --links --stats --rsh="ssh -p 2222 -l user" www.example.com:/home/user/public_html/ /home/user/public_html/rsynctest`

Current behavior is that I get `/home/user/public_html/rsynctest/home/user/public_html/`. All files in public_html are copied successfully, but I get layers of directories that I don't want.

My desired behavior is that the contents of `public_html` from example.com are mirrored to the folder `rsynctest` on the local machine (I retain `/home/user/public_html` instead of creating the double layered directory structure). How can I achieve this? I thought the trailing slash on the remote directory was supposed to do it, but it's not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
rsync -zavr --delete --links --stats --rsh="ssh -p 2222 -l user" www.example.com:/home/user/public_html/ /home/user/public_html/rsynctest/.
```

Is there any reason you are including the -R option. That's what's making rsync save your relative paths (directories)

Comment: From the rsync man page:

 -R, --relative
              Use relative paths. This means that the full path names specified on the command line are
              sent to the server rather than just the last parts of the filenames.

Comment: Aha! I thought I had reviewed all the options, clearly not. I am adapting from a NixCraft article http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-use-rsync-transfer-mirror-files-directories.html.